# Google Glass GDK: get current item on CardScrollView

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

How can we get the current position, or the current item, of the CardScrollView?  I have not seen a getCurrentPosition() or public getItem() on CardScrollView or CardScrollAdapter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CardScrollView` [(javadoc link)](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/widget/CardScrollView) has the methods `getSelectedItem()` to return the item associated with the currently selected card, and `getSelectedItemPosition()` to return its index.

Comment: Yep, `getSelectedItem` workd for me... but make sure that you call `setItemOnCard` in your `CardScrollAdapter`'s `getView` override. Otherwise, `getSelectedItem()` will return null.

Comment: Have you tried replicating this result with the latest GDK release? setItemOnCard is now deprecated.